# How do I read from sys.config in my ejabberd release?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I'm running ejabberd 23.01- I would like to read some values from my sys.config file.

When running ejabberd as relive in VSCode, running `ejabberdctl debug` and running `application:get_env(ejabberd, config).` gives me a tuple containing the `ejabberd.yml` path. I've deduced that this path comes from the `relive.config` file, and I've been able to successfully store and read my values from the file as well.

My issue is however, with the release- making the same modifications to `sys.config` and then making a release by running `make rel` pushes the sys.config file to the `releases/23.01` folder, and upon starting the release from `bin/ejabberdctl start` and running `bin/ejabberdctl debug`+`application:get_env(ejabberd, config).`, it returns an `undefined` value.

What am I missing? Am I starting up my ejabberd release wrong(in a way that does not keep `sys.config` in mind while starting the application)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a workaround - not the best, but it works, and it's configurable and probably more so than the `sys.config` route.

I made another module that reads options from the ejabberd.yml file, and on module startup, uses `application:set_env/3` to set application variables for the target application.

This will obviously fail if the application is functions (that are dependent on these values) are triggered before the envs are set, but it works for my use case.